# Reload page 2 times with ajax / javascript and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I must admit I am not good with Ajax, Java script or CSS to be honest. Please go easy on me I need help. I am using a CMS that I wrapped in Jquery mobile and can't use meta refresh methods. How do I make the page reload only 2 times at specified times with the code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload();
}, 2000);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload();
}, 15000);
});
</script>
```

The problem that I am having is that it ignores the second one and keeps going in a loop. I know there is a simple solution to this.

Comment: Of course it goes in a loop. When you reload the page, javascript starts again. The second action is destroyed on page unload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need persistence to overcome the loop problem.
This is because every time the page gets reloaded, the javascript in it is evaluated.
Your page should "remember" that it has been reloaded. ...how?
There are many ways. You could add a parameter to the query string, or save this data in a cookie or in the local storage. You could keep track of the reloads server-side. 
Every approach has its own pros and cons.

Here's a simple working solution, close to the one you are looking for, that uses the localStorage (old browsers don't support localStorage http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ;(function () {
        var reloads = [2000, 13000],
            storageKey = 'reloadIndex',
            reloadIndex = parseInt(localStorage.getItem(storageKey), 10) || 0;

        if (reloadIndex >= reloads.length || isNaN(reloadIndex)) {
            localStorage.removeItem(storageKey);
            return;
        }

        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.reload();
        }, reloads[reloadIndex]);

        localStorage.setItem(storageKey, parseInt(reloadIndex, 10) + 1);
    }());
</script>
```

As you can see, I use an array that contains some kind of timeline. To keep things simple,  every element of the array contains the number of milliseconts to to wait before changing the page since the last reload.

Comment: This works and is the answer. I have not seen a lot of setTimeout reload page stackoverflow questions that use localStorage as a solution. I am okay with it not being supported by old browsers because its strictly for cell phone use only.

Comment: Moreover, this was a good temporary solution for Jquery mobile select menu issues that use Jquery/ Ajax to pull data from a db. In my case it would not work correctly unless I reloaded the entire page. Notice the words "temporary solution" since you should always find out what the real problem is and fix it.