# How can I reload a page automatically every n seconds from the address bar?

Tags: javascript, html

Looking for a cross-platform solution for this. I have access to an intranet site that does not implement auto-refresh. I tried this code, but it only refreshes the page once. I want it to refresh every 5 seconds, and from the server, not the cache.

```
javascript:void(setInterval(function(){window.location.reload();},5000))
```

Any tips are welcome.

Comment: Consider a browser plugin.  No need to reinvent the wheel.  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-refresh-plus/oilipfekkmncanaajkapbpancpelijih?hl=en

Comment: It has to be cross-browser, so I can't use existing plugins. It must work in IE and Opera too.

Comment: Have you considered signalR?

Comment: Can you add a meta tag to the html?

Comment: What you're asking for is really a browser-based functionality since you cannot modify the page, so it doesn't make sense to ask for it to be cross-browser...

Comment: Lucas, I tried adding the meta refresh tag, unfortunately that does not work in IE. user193130, I have tried executing JS in the address bar before and it has worked. I wonder why setTimeout and setInterval are doing the same thing :(

Comment: When you reload the page, it clears the interval.

Comment: Related: [Reload page 2 times with ajax / javascript and setTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314748/reload-page-2-times-with-ajax-javascript-and-settimeout)

Comment: Thank you christian314159, I figured this might be happening. Looks like there's no way around it

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked in Chrome, didn't test it anywhere else but I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work:

```
javascript:document.documentElement.style.height%3D%22100%25%22%3Bdocument.body.style.height%3D%22100%25%22%3Bdocument.body.style.margin%3D0%3Bdocument.body.style.padding%3D0%3Bdocument.body.innerHTML%3D%22%3Ciframe%20width%3D100%25%20height%3D100%25%20frameborder%3D0%3E%3C%2Fiframe%3E%22%3Bvar%20frame%3Ddocument.getElementsByTagName(%27iframe%27)%5B0%5D%3BsetInterval(function()%7Bframe.src%3Ddocument.location%7D%2C%205000)%3Bframe.src%3Ddocument.location%3B
```

Note: when you copy-paste this to Chrome's address bar it apparently strips `javascript:` from the beginning, I suppose for security reasons). Make sure to add it back.

Line by line:

```
// Making sure the document doesn't have margin or padding
// and it takes up the whole screen
document.documentElement.style.height="100%";
document.body.style.height="100%";
document.body.style.margin=0;
document.body.style.padding=0;

// Replacing the current contents with an iframe that 
fills the whole document
document.body.innerHTML="<iframe width=100% height=100% frameborder=0></iframe>";

// Finding the iframe
var frame=document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];

// Scheduling refresh in every 5s
setInterval(function(){frame.src=document.location}, 5000);

// Loading the original page in the iframe
// for the first time
frame.src=document.location;
```